# How can I make histogram using python/plotly like this?

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, visualization

I want to make histogram of a column in my dataset using python that looks similar like this which I got from excel, I would like to have an overflow bin as in this picture below:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass custom bin sizes into numpys histogram function:

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, bins=your_bins)
```

Plot with matplotlib as usual and set custom labels as described here:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in terms of how to customize the x-axis scale. As @the_strage already answered about the histogram, you can set any scale, so I will answer using the resulting value. Using the values obtained, draw a bar chart with the number of classes and the number of frequencies, and update it with the x-axis ticks and a new tick string. The bar interval is then set to zero.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

hist, bins = np.histogram(np.random.randint(36, 100, 100), bins=[36,54,72,75,100])
    
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=[0,1,2,3], y=hist))

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0,1,2,3], ticktext=['(36,54]','(54,72]','(72,75]','>75'])
fig.update_layout(bargap=0)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful; however, the overflow bin is not showing up in my graph:

This is my code:

Comment: Is there an issue with your question without data or code when you are told that the overflow bins are not displayed? Furthermore, you are using my answer to your next question.